# Unable to exclude jboss log4j logmanager module on EAP 6.4.2

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j

I am using EAP 6.4.2. We have an ear application which listens to log4j LogEvents published over IBM mq topic.

```
Host APP sends LogggingEvent using log4j jms appender => Topic => myApps mdb
```

I am trying to read this LoggingEvent object using an MDB. However reading the jms message (object message) results in a NullPointer:

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.readObject(LoggingEvent.java:290) ~[log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsObjectMessageImpl.getObjectInternal(JmsObjectMessageImpl.java:390) ~[com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.jar:?]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsObjectMessageImpl.getObject(JmsObjectMessageImpl.java:318) ~[com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.jar:?]
        ... 73 more
```

From the stack its clear that instead of using the log4j jar packaged in my ear, jboss's `log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar` jar is being used. I tried to exclude this using `ear/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" />
            <module name="ch.qos" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="myapp-listener.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" />
            <module name="ch.qos" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

However this exclusion has no effect. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
As suggested in comments, the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674062/unable-to-exclude-logmanager-module-on-jboss-6-eap) does not work. I have already added these exclusions to jboss xml.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to exclude logmanager module on JBoss 6 EAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674062/unable-to-exclude-logmanager-module-on-jboss-6-eap)

Comment: @AlejandroGoñi not really. I have already added the exclusions mentioned in the answer, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that issue was with using container managed mq connection factory.
This is how the application was reading messages

```
app -> MDB -> jndi -> connection factory -> mq resource adapter jar -> bound to jboss-log4j
```

The mq resource adapter was bound to the jboss-log4j jar. So when I try to read an object message off the topic, it uses the jboss-log4j jar instead of the application provided log4j.

I worked around this by removing dependencies on the container provided resource adapter and removing the JNDI lookup. Replaced the MDB with a spring jms listener which works off mq jars packaged inside my ear.